# Log file getting spammed by "writing header" when calling service

Tags: ros

I have a rospy node that hosts a very simple service, indicating if a modem is ready to send data. Another node calls this service very often. For some reason, the following log statement gets logged every time the service gets called.

```
./EnhancedAcomms.log:47152:[rospy.tcpros][DEBUG] 2021-07-06 04:54:22,451: [/EnhancedModemDriver/ReadyToSend]: writing header
```

Note the "writing header" above. Nothing in my code logs this.

This is the service file

```
---
bool ready
```

This is the actual service

```
def _readyToSendServiceHandler(self, request):
    readyToSend = self._micromodemDriver.readyToSend()
    res = ReadyToSendResponse()
    res.ready = readyToSend
    return readyToSend
```

This is how it's called

```
_readyToSend = rospy.ServiceProxy(self.readyToSendServiceName, ReadyToSend)
res = _readyToSend()
return res.ready
```

Does anyone have any idea where this is coming from (what is rospy.tcpros?) and why it's getting logged constantly? This is the ONLY service in a package with a dozen services that does this.

Answer (score 2):

> Does anyone have any idea where this is coming from

Looks like line 640 of [rospy.impl.tcpros_base](http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/rospy/html/rospy.impl.tcpros_base-pysrc.html):

```
logger.debug("[%s]: writing header", self.name)
```

> and why it's getting logged constantly?

The particular message is logged with a call to `logger.debug` which is putting this message in your log file. It's getting written every time the `write_header` method is called, which happens in line 561 of [the same file](http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/rospy/html/rospy.impl.tcpros_base-pysrc.html). That, in turn, is part of the `try` block that's trying to setup your connection in the `connect` method.

I would guess you're getting spammed with the message because you're spamming calls to the `connect` method. You said that this is "a very simple service, indicating if a modem is ready to send data," but how does it work? Does it try to make a connection and indicate read-to-send when the connection status is good?

My immediate reaction was that there are bound to be more responses in your log file, but in looking at the `catch` section of the `connect` method, I see the following:

```
except TransportInitError as tie: 
    rospyerr("Unable to initiate TCP/IP socket to %s:%s (%s): %s"%(dest_addr, dest_port, endpoint_id, traceback.format_exc()))             
    raise 
except Exception as e: 
    #logerr("Unknown error initiating TCP/IP socket to %s:%s (%s): %s"%(dest_addr, dest_port, endpoint_id, str(e))) 
    rospywarn("Unknown error initiating TCP/IP socket to %s:%s (%s): %s"%(dest_addr, dest_port, endpoint_id, traceback.format_exc()))
```

So while your `write_header` code is using `logger.debug`, your exceptions are being written to `rospyerr` and `rospywarn`. To view those, follow the steps for [reading your log messages](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Logging#Reading_log_messages).

If there really aren't any other log messages, in the local logs or on the /rosout topic, then you should try to investigate further into how that code is getting called - again it looks like you're spamming the connect call.

Looking at your service, it looks like you've got some stuff you're not doing anything with. You're calling

```
readyToSend = self._micromodemDriver.readyToSend()
return readyToSend
```

and I can't tell what `.readyToSend()` is doing and then also you've got:

```
res = ReadyToSendResponse()
res.ready = readyToSend
```

and I can't tell what the `res` is for (you're not returning it) and I can't see what `ReadyToSendResponse` is doing AND I can't tell why you have two very similarly-named functions, `readyToSend()` and `ReadyToSendResponse()`.

Check for other logs and /rosout and see if you're getting exceptions from the `connect` call, then try to dig down into your code and see if you're calling `connect` on a loop somewhere.